# How do i make part of a CSS background fit perfectly to a browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to CSS and so i dont really know how to describe it but here is an example:[website](http://www.vestorly.com/)

As you can see the background image at the top of the website fits perfect in height and width to the space of any browser regardless of the resolution. As you scroll down the page it keeps the same style where a specific background color fits closely to the space of the browser. I have tested this on a laptop as well as mobile and it fits closely each time. How do i achieve this? Is it doable purely from CSS or do i have to involve JavaScript/Jquery, etc? I have seen many websites use this specific style and i would like to understand hoe it is done.

I am not asking specifically for code, just an answer that states what it is i should be searching for. Code is appreciated however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your browser's developer tools to see exactly how that site creates the effect. It's a combination of CSS and JavaScript.

The CSS:

```
.homepage-intro.homepage {
    background: url("//d1sva73gxwx496.cloudfront.net/images/homepage/bg-intro-2039a477.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The JavaScript then explicitly sets the height of the `<div>` to match the browser window.

Comment: For cover it says the following: it does not assure that some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area. Does using javascript and then explicitly setting the height of the div to match the browser window forces the image to fit within the viewable part of the browser?

Comment: A better description is at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), but the short answer is yes, it will fill the window.

Answer (score 2):

There are different approaches. If you inspect the site you linked, they are using background cover to accomplish this. `background-size: cover;` It will fill up the width and height of the current div.

See this article for more info: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 2):

That site is using JavaScript to set the height of the `<div>` that has that background image. Combined with `background-size: cover;`, that should do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure the bottom of your div hits the bottom of the browser window, you can do this via CSS.

#### CSS

```css
div {
    height:100vh;
}
```

or

```css
body, html {
   height: 100%;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will require CSS and jQuery to do this effectively (and also to allow for cross-browser support).

**CSS**

```
//Add this to your background image's CSS.
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
```

**jQuery**

```
var viewportHeight = jQuery(window).height();
//wrote an if statement to allow for a minimum height. You can remove this if statement if you don't need it.
if(viewportHeight>500){
     jQuery('page-wrapper').height(viewportHeight);
}else{
     jQuery('page-wrapper').height(500);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, you need to accomplish two tasks:

1. Make the background-image always adjust to the size of the container. This is done, as others have already stated, by assigning `background-size: cover;` to the container element on which you placed the image as a `background-image`. Add `background-position: center;` for better results on low resolution devices as well as portrait orientation.
2. Make sure the container element stretches 100% of the viewport's width in both directions. Block level elements per default grab 100% of the available width, but you need to set an explicit height to match the desired layout. This can be achieved by applying `height: 100vh;` (100% viewport height) to the container element. Check if the unit `vh` is usable on the devices you plan the layout for: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

If you need to support browsers that do not recognize `vh` it's probably the easiest solution to use javascript (or jQuery) to dynamically assign a height to your container element.

This is how it's done in jQuery for a `<div id="my-container-element"></div>`

`$("#my-container-element").height($(window).css("height");`

Same in pure Javascript:

`document.getElementById("my-container-element").style.height(window.innerHeight+"px");`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your CSS sheet:

```
html {  background: url(myImage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;}
```

It will fill the whole page with your background Image.

Comment: Would this fill the whole page or just the part being viewed in the browser? I am looking for the ladder.

Comment: Even if you zoom out it would fill the whole page yes.

Comment: Sorry i guess my question was not worded very well, i am looking to have it fill only the portion currently being viewed, not actually the entire page.

Comment: Well when i load that website, the first background image fits pefectly to the current viewable browser space. I tested this on a laptop and an ipad and the result is the same.